# Laravel not returning value zero in the session... why?

Tags: laravel, laravel-10

I am not sure if there is something wrong with the code or if this is how it is supposed to work... why is the 0 not printing on the view?

```
$val = 1; // this works and renders a 1 on the view
$val = 'abc'; // this works and renders abc on the view
$val = 0; // this does not render anything on the view
```

```
return redirect('home')->with([ 'val' => $val ]);
```

The blade has:

```
@if (session('val'))
<div>
   {{ session('val') }}
</div>
@endif
```

Update:

This issue happens when the redirect is happening on the same page as the page from where it is initiated.

I have got a button on `home`. On the click on this button, the value of `val` is computed by a controller function which redirects back to `home` with `val` in the session. If I redirect to any other page, say `dashboard`, the 0 shows up.

Comment: Because 0 is falsy, so the `@if` check is false with 0 as the value. Try with: `@if (isset(session('val'))` as an alternative ... see [this information](https://www.php.net/manual/en/types.comparisons.php)

Comment: Also, before that if, you can add: `@php dd($__data); @endphp` to see everything being passed to the blade. (that's a double underscore in the `dd` example)

Comment: @PaulT. `dd($__data)` was helpful, thanks; it helped in confirming that the session do not contain `val` if its value is 0.

Comment: Another alternative is `@if(session()->has('val'))`; that should return `true` if you've done `->with(['val' => 0])` following a `redirect()`, or manually setting into the session via `session()->put('val', 0)`. `session('val')` is shorthand for `session()->get('val')`, which if `0`, fails the `@if()` check as Paul T. stated, but `session()->has()` will return `true` if the session key is there (regardless of its value), or `false` if it is not.

Comment: @TimLewis I tried `session()->put` but it did not make any difference.

Comment: I found that this behavior is happening when redirecting to the same page. I would updated the question now.